# ffmpeg create segments from rtmp stream deterministicly

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I want to use `ffmpeg` to "convert" live RTMP stream to hls or mpeg-dash. For redundancy purposes I would like to run multiple `ffmpeg`s simultaneously for one RTMP stream.

The problem is, when I start two ffmpeg for already running rtmp stream, they start to generate different video segments.

I would hope, there is some way, to generate those segments in a more 'deterministic' way, for example, based on the rtmp timestamp.

Is there any way to get two ffmpeg to generate same segments, to somehow sync them? Thanks.

---

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -listen 1 -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/stream/test \
  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 \
  -b:v:0 250k -filter:v:0 "scale=-2:240" -profile:v:0 baseline \
  -b:v:1 750k -filter:v:1 "scale=-2:480" -profile:v:1 main \
  -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -window_size 5 \
  -hls_playlist 1 \
  -dash_segment_type mp4 \
  -window_size 0 \
  -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
  -f dash \
  -hls_base_url 'http://example.com' \
  test.mpd
```

Notes:

- FFmpeg in this hls/dash mode does two main things, generate video segments, and generate manifests. I do not really care about the manifests, I can generate them other ways, using custom scripts. The only thing I need are those segments
- Starting ffmpeg before rtmp start, or theoretically starting both at exactly the same time results in same segments, but I am really looking for a way to be able to start and stop them at any point in time.